# Generate href value from a variable in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller action method-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:50926/";
   return View();
}
```

In ViewPage-

```
<a href="@ViewBag.BaseUrl/page.html">One</a>
```

This generates url as follows (notice the double slash at end)

```
"http://localhost:50926//page.html"
```

How to get rid of double slash? Please note that `BaseUrl` value can not be changed.

Comment: You can write some extension method which will remove all extra slashes and use it everywhere in the project. Do you need an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to avoid the extra slash before `page.html`. But you can't leave this text just near the variable. You must do that way :

```
<a href="@(ViewBag.BaseUrl)page.html">One</a>
```

In this case you will get `"http://localhost:50926/page.html"` without the unexpected double slash.

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you're looking for:

```
<a href="@(ViewBag.BaseUrl+"page.html")">One</a>
```

Comment: I think it's not 100% safe. If `ViewBag.BaseUrl` doesn't contain ending slash then broken URL will be generated. This behavior is much more worse then double slashes

Comment: @dimonser I'm not sure what do you expect from this code. Every peace of code can broke on some conditions. But i don't think that you should write tons of code to avoid all errors. It's just not worth it.

Comment: I think we should write safe code, especially in this case. Broken URLs generate angry users.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your view :

```
@{
     Uri baseUri = new Uri(ViewBag.BaseUrl);
     Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/page.html");
 }
```

and then use @myUri every place you want.